# Anyone else experience jerkiness in games when holding shift key down?

Tags: keyboard, medal-of-honor

I was just playing Medal of Honor.  Every time I ran the framerate and my movement would become jerky.  I use right shift to run (I'm left handed so use the right side of the keyboard for movement).    I tried just holding the shift key and not moving - looking at the moving scenery (in this case trees waving in the wind) I could see the jerkiness.

I re-assigned the run key to a different key (delete) and this didn't cause jerking, but shift still did.  I'd prefer to use shift for running so I need to fix this.  Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Maybe your keyboard has hardware limitations? Does it happen to be wireless? Is it USB or older connector?

Comment: USB.   It's a logitech wave.     I think it's ok now.

Comment: it came back. 2

Comment: so... I guess now that this post is a few days old it will be forgotten.

Comment: Pressing left-shift 5 times in a row triggers accessibility options, which might interfere with the game's performance. Can you confirm that?

Comment: In Windows, holding down the right SHIFT key for 8 seconds turns on FilterKeys. Try deactivating the key combo for filter keys, or see if right SHIFT is mapped elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever figure out the problem? If not, have you tried updating your keyboard drivers from [Logitech](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/434/3071)? I'd start there. I'd also check to see if any other programs running in the background have right-shift bound.

If that doesn't work, have you tried swapping out keyboards? That should give you an idea if it's your computer/software or the hardware.

Good luck.